# Euclid's Extended GCD Inverse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to make sense out of this table.

[image]

I understand the $k,j,q$, and $r$ part but I don't understand how they get the $x$ and the $Y$. Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: @pjs36 thank you for the edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each step (going upwards), the algorithm computes a vector (x,y). The vector obtained at the previous step is denoted $(x',y)'$, $q$ is the current quotient, and the relation between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ is given by 
$$x=y'-qx', \quad y=x'.$$
For instance, having obtained $(7,-3)$ (3rd line from bottom) the next vector will be $x=-3-6\cdot 7-45,\quad y=7$.

Comment: Okay, so you start at the bottom and work your way up, can you give me one more example? I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: So to compute the third line from the bottom, it would be 1 from the line before it's `y`, 2 from the current line's `q`, and -3 from the previous lines `x`?

Comment: Well, personally, I do this in parallel with the Euclidean algorithm,i.e. I start at the top and go downwards. As I see it, here, you start with $x=1, y=0$. At the next step, you have $q=3$, whence $x=0-3\cdot1=-3, y=1$.  One more step: $q=2$, whence $x=1-2\cdot -3=7, y=-3$.

Comment: Your description is correct.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now, sorry for all the questions, but I have a test on the matter in an hour or so. How would one go about computing the bottom line?

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. What do you mean with ‘how would one compute the bottom line’? The last two columns are initialised at $(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh okay, so just to clarify my overthinking self, no matter what values are used in the table, the bottom x and y will always be (1,0)?

Comment: Yes, they're the initial values of the procedure.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for being the professor I wish I had!

Comment: You're welcome!  Just a small question: is it the procedure you've been taught, or is it just an example taken in a book or in course notes?